# Check if string in strings

Tags: python, string, list, comparison

I have a huge list containing many strings like:

```
['xxxx','xx','xy','yy','x',......]
```

Now I am looking for an efficient way that removes all strings that are present within another string. For example 'xx' 'x' fit in 'xxxx'.

As the dataset is huge, I was wondering if there is an efficient method for this beside

`if a in b:`

The complete code: With maybe some optimization parts:

```
for x in range(len(taxlistcomplete)):
if delete == True:
    x = x - 1
    delete = False
for y in range(len(taxlistcomplete)):
    if taxlistcomplete[x] in taxlistcomplete[y]:
        if x != y:
            print x,y
            print taxlistcomplete[x]
            del taxlistcomplete[x]
            delete = True
            break
    print x, len(taxlistcomplete)
```

An updated version of the code:

```
for x in enumerate(taxlistcomplete):
if delete == True:
    #If element is removed, I need to step 1 back and continue looping.....
    delete = False
for y in enumerate(taxlistcomplete):
    if x[1] in y[1]:
        if x[1] != y[1]:
            print x[1],y[1]
            print taxlistcomplete[x]

            del taxlistcomplete[x[0]]
            delete = True
            break
print x, len(taxlistcomplete)
```

Now implemented with the enumerate, only now I am wondering if this is more efficient and howto implement the delete step so I have less to search in as well.

Just a short thought...

Basically what I would like to see...

if element does not match any other elements in list write this one to a file.
Thus if 'xxxxx' not in 'xx','xy','wfirfj',etc... print/save

A new simple version as I dont think I can optimize it much further anyway...

```
print 'comparison'

file = open('output.txt','a')

for x in enumerate(taxlistcomplete):
    delete = False
    for y in enumerate(taxlistcomplete):
        if x[1] in y[1]:
            if x[1] != y[1]:
                taxlistcomplete[x[0]] = ''
                delete = True
                break
    if delete == False:
        file.write(str(x))
```

Comment: Does the order of the strings matter?

Comment: Fix your indentation, this is not valid python code. It's not clear what you mean to be doing.

Comment: Convert your list to a set, `in` will be faster.

Comment: Note that looping over a range to the length of a list is incredibly unpythonic, loop over the values, and use `enumerate()` if you need the index with it.

Comment: Order is indeed irrelevant, I only need to remove all the items that match other items partly. like 'egg' in 'eggplant' then egg needs to be removed.

Comment: Is the length of each individual string capped? Are they mostly short, or can each string also be huge?

Comment: @rubik converting the list to a set would help if we were looking for an exact match, but we are actually checking for substrings in any of the existing strings.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Yes, you're right. I read the post before the edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`x in <string>` is fast, but checking each string against all other strings in the list will take O(n^2) time. Instead of shaving a few cycles by optimizing the comparison, you can achieve huge savings by using a different data structure so that you can check each string in just one lookup: For two thousand strings, that's two thousand checks instead of four million.

There's a data structure called a "prefix tree" (or trie) that allows you to very quickly check whether a string is a prefix of some string you've seen before. Google it. Since you're also interested in strings that occur *in the middle* of another string `x`, index all substrings of the form `x, x[1:], x[2:], x[3:],` etc. (So: only `n` substrings for a string of length `n`). That is, you index substrings that start in position 0, 1, 2, etc. and continue to the end of the string. That way you can just check if a new string is an *initial* part of something in your index.

You can then solve your problem in O(n) time like this:

1. Order your strings in order of decreasing length. This ensures that no string could be a substring of something you haven't seen yet. Since you only care about length, you can do a bucket sort in O(n) time.
2. Start with an empty prefix tree and loop over your ordered list of strings. For each string `x`, use your prefix tree to check whether it is a substring of a string you've seen before. If not, add its substrings `x, x[1:], x[2:]` etc. to the prefix tree.

Deleting in the middle of a long list is very expensive, so you'll get a further speedup if you collect the strings you want to keep into a new list (the actual string is not copied, just the reference). When you're done, delete the original list and the prefix tree.

If that's too complicated for you, at least don't compare everything with everything. Sort your strings by size (in decreasing order), and only check each string against the ones that have come before it. This will give you a 50% speedup with very little effort. And do make a new list (or write to a file immediately) instead of deleting in place.

Comment: The problem is that I will have 861 element (this is not correct, a recheck would however take a while. The number is much higher) possibilities if I understood you correctly. Y is indeed considered as a substring of XY. Thus X and Y can match XY and both will be removed. Might not sound logical but with this dataset it is. :)

Comment: Deleting the elements should also make the search faster eventually as there are less elements to search in right?

Comment: Matching Y inside XY makes sense, I was just hoping for an easy out :-) But deletion won't help you much, unless most of your strings are duplicates.

Comment: Well deleting would be nice so I have a list in the end that I can use. Or I can rename the elements that are not needed to ''

Comment: I meant, deletion won't speed things up. Anyway it's usually quicker  to make a new list with the strings you want to keep than to delete lots of strings from the middle of a list.

Comment: I indeed came up with the same solution when I was driving home in the bus. Sort by length and of course! The longest can never match in a shorter string. Doesn't python implement the IN statement in the same way? IF length > comparing string / Skip.

Comment: Python probably does short-circuit substring checking this way, but you'll still waste time on a whole lot of no-ops if you try to check everything against everything. Anyway, the real reason for proposing this order is to make sure that when you check a string, everything you need is already in the index. Have fun with it!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple approach, assuming you can identify a character (I will use `'$'` in my example) that is guaranteed not to be in any of the original strings:

```
result = ''
for substring in taxlistcomplete:
    if substring not in result: result += '$' + substring
taxlistcomplete = result.split('$')
```

This leverages Python's internal optimizations for substring searching by just making one big string to substring-search :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension -- note `in` -- is the fastest and more Pythonic way of solving your problem:

```
[element for element in arr if 'xx' in element]
```

Comment: He wants to remove all elements that are in another element (any element).

Comment: Oh, seems like I didn't get that, after the edit it's clear. nevertheless is `in` the fastest way of checking if a string is inside another.

Comment: But is it the fastest way of determining how many strings in a list are contained by some other element of that list?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion. First I sort the elements by length. Because obviously the shorter the string is, the more likely it is to be a substring of another string. Then I have two for loops, where I run through the list and remove every element from the list where el is a substring. Note that the first for loop only passes each element once.

By sortitng the list first, we destroy the order of elements in the list. So if the order is important, then you can't use this solution.

Edit. I assume there are no identical elements in the list. So that when el == el2, it's because its the same element.

```
a = ["xyy", "xx", "zy", "yy", "x"]
a.sort(key=len)

for el in a:
    for el2 in a:
        if el in el2 and el != el2:
            a.remove(el2)
```